# How to get latest mail using imapclient in python?

Tags: python

How to get latest mail using `imapclient` in python.

I already tried with imaplib but I want latest mail in imapclient.

```
>>> import imapclient
>>> imapObj = imapclient.IMAPClient('imap.gmail.com', ssl=True)
>>> imapObj.login('my_email_address@gmail.com', 'MY_SECRET_PASSWORD')
'my_email_address@gmail.com Jane Doe authenticated (Success)'
>>> imapObj.select_folder('INBOX', readonly=True)
>>> UIDs = imapObj.search(['SINCE 05-Jul-2014'])
```